# Remove element from a list generated with range in python?

Tags: python

Here's a simple program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

l = list(range(5))
print(l, type(l))

l = list(range(5)).remove(2)
print(l, type(l))
```

for some reason the list is destroyed on removing the element:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] <class 'list'>
None <class 'NoneType'>
```

(it is program output)

I expected it to output

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

What is wrong, and how do I remove the element from a list generated with `range`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are storing the return value of the `list.remove()` call,  not the list itself. The `list.remove()` call alters the list in place and returns `None`. It does *not* return the altered list.

Store the list first:

```
l = list(range(5))
l.remove(2)
```

or use a list comprehension to filter:

```
l = [i for i in range(5) if i != 2]
```

Comment: So how do I remove the element?